# Cannot post my question because of code formatting

Tags: bug, markdown, code-formatting

I tried to post a question on the Mathematica forum, I spend a hour writing it correctly and I have the following error when I want to submit it: "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code."

This is my post:

> Hello.
>
> I have a set of coupled Ordinary Differential Equations of the form :
>
> ```
> $$
> N'(r)=\mathcal{D}N(r,N,Y,U,P), \\
> Y'(r)=\mathcal{D}Y(r,N,Y,U,P), \\
> U'(r)=\mathcal{D}U(r,N,Y,U,P), \\
> P'(r)=\mathcal{D}P(r,N,Y,U,P),
> $$
> ```
>
> and I would like to solve it numerically with the numerical solver of Mathematica. The explicit forms of these equations are not very
> instructive here because they are complicated (for your information,
> it is the field equations of a modified theory of gravity with
> spherical symmetry).
>
> For my purpose here, I have an initial condition at a large radius and I want to integrate backward in $r$ until $R=1.0$. Therefore,
> after defining my equations and my conditions, I use the following
> instruction
>
> ```
>     sm = NDSolve[{eqn, eqY, eqU, eqp, n[rmax] == nmax, Y[rmax] == Ymax,U[rmax] == Umax,p[rmax]==0.0}, {n, Y, U, p}, {r, 1.0, rmax},AccuracyGoal -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 10] // Flatten
> ```
>
> The integration seems successful since I have the following output without any errors
>
> [image: Output of NDSolve without any errors]
>
> But then, when I want to plot the solution (for example the function $N(r)$) with the command :
>
> ```
>     plotm = Plot[Evaluate[n[r] /. sm], {r, 1.0, rmax},PlotTheme -> "Scientific", ImageSize -> Large]
> ```
>
> there is nothing under $r\approx 5$ even though the integration domain is $[1.0,r_{\text{max}}]$. See on this picture what I get
>
> [image: Plot]
>
> I have the same problem by plotting $Y(r)$ or $U(r)$ (but their plots stop at different radius). It looks like the integrator failed
> to reach $R=1$ but usually, it prints an error message in this case.
>
> Even more weird, if I ask directly for the numerical value of $N(r)$, it seems to work perfectly. For example, with the instruction
>
> ```
>     For[i = 0, i <= 100, i++, Block[{r}, r = 1 + 49.0/100 i; Print[r, "\t", n[r] /. sm]]]
> ```
>
> I get the following result
>
> [image: Numerical values]
>
> I have tried to change the vertical axis range on the plot : it changes nothing. The plot stops below some value of $r$ greater than
> 1.
>
> I am not on expert with these features of Mathematica so may be I have forgotten something obvious but actually I do not see what it is.
>
> Any idea ?
>
> Thank you !

I lost an other hour trying to find the problem, looking for answers on this forum but I still can't fix it...

I used the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> shortcut to indent my code.

Any idea?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I see, thanks. Romain, see this line "AccuracyGoal -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 10] // Flatten" it is not formatted

Comment: It was formatted but @πάνταῥεῖ editted my post and make this line out of the identation wrong...

Comment: You formatted all the text as code and he fixed it. Is the previous version how it was when you posted it?

Comment: @RomainGervalle Feel free to [edit] your question again. But please leave plain text formatted as cite in the text and not as code.

Comment: All those bits with the $ would need to be formatted too, you can wrap them in ` to format in the middle of a sentence. Like this `$Y(r)$`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes sorry for this mistake, I fixed it. But I still can't find what is my problem...

Comment: @RomainGervalle Are the image links really formatted as code in the question?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The Mathematica forum exists : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RomainGervalle Oh sorry, I didn't know about SE Mathematica. The question should go to SE Meta Mathematica though. And don't call any SE Q&A site a _forum_ please, that's a big annoyance and misunderstanding.

Comment: No, the image links are not formatted as code, it is again a mistake of editing...

Comment: Try posting it again without the original code formatting, the version *after* it was edited by @πάντα ῥεῖ  it looks fine from where I am. But remove the blockquote formatting, that grey sidebar.

Comment: @MarkKirby I though that $ can be used to put inline LaTeX text, isn't it ?

Comment: Oh, yes you are right, I got confused because it is not supported here, so does not render the LaTeX, ignore that suggestion.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There is a Meta Mathematica SE ? Sorry for the use the word *forum*.

Comment: I found the Meta Mathematica but I cannot post on it because I need 5 reputation points. It seems like I will never be able to post my question and I lost my entire afternoon trying to fix it...

Comment: See: [How can I easily copy Mathematica code for use with this site? (We have a palette for this!)](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/151/63507) ***and*** [How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1584/63507) - the multi-line MathJax seems to work on Mathematica.SE: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhwjq.jpg

Comment: Yes it work on the preview, but try to post a question with a multiline LaTeX, it won't work.

Comment: What you wrote is invalid LaTeX/MathJax syntax. You cannot use `\\ ` in plain `$$ ... $$` to get newlines. If you want to format several equations in a single command, you may use for example `$$\begin{align} a&=b\\ c&=d\\ e&=f \end{align}$$`. (This is how it is written in MathJax; in actual LaTeX, this would come without the `$$`s.)

Answer (score 8):

Ok, I finally found the problem and it seems to be a bug with LaTeX formatting.

I post here the solution to help further SE users. The multiline LaTeX formatting (with $$ symbol) does not work at all for the moment even if you follow the good syntax (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

It is very weird because in the preview, multiline LaTeX appears correctly.

Comment: Are you sure? It does work in this recent answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/217101 .